Flutter App Running Default Counter App Instead of Custom Login Page
I'm working on a Flutter project where I’ve created a custom login page. However, when I run the project using flutter run in VS Code, the app displays the default counter app that comes with a new Flutter project instead of my login page.

Can you please show your main.dart?

In your MaterialApp of main.dart file replace home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'), with home: your login screen.
